# Add data to table through another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First of all: I have 4 tables:

1) `respondents` with `id` and `email`.

2) `inquires` with id, question_id, `respondent_id`

3) `question_id` with `id` and `text`

4) `answers` with `inquiry_id`, `text`

What i want? I want to do next: in my view I have `question` and `text_field` and `button`. 
If user something answer on question and press button, this data inserts into `answer` table.

my_controller (asnwer_controller)

```
  def create
    if request.post?
      Answer.create(:inquiry_id=>@inquiry.id.to_s, :text=>params[:text])
    end
  end
```

my_view

```
<% form_for :answer, :url => { :controller => 'answer', :action => 'create' } do |f| %>
    <%= @questions.id %>. <%= @questions.text %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :text, :rols => 10, :cols => 60 %><br />
    <%= submit_tag "Send Survey ", :class => "inputBox" %>
<% end %>
```

I through i something missed in view & controller. Data not pasting now. Please help!

Comment: I through this is help-webpage where people help each other and don't care about 1% of they reputation, but i think i was wrong.

Comment: Which is true. But you have to show that you care about the community. When people help you, it's not so bad to show your acknowledgment by clicking the little check sign.

Comment: Ok!, i just a few months here, and I didn't know what this buttons are doing, now i know, and already clicked.

Comment: Now, i will try to answer your question. I hope i understand what you ask.

Comment: Thank you! I just need to paste data through form where textarea only into answers table (through inquiry table)

Comment: Why are you editing all of your questions to garbage? I've rolled back all of them. Please stop, other people might want to read your questions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand the question, you want to add data through an intermediate table. So, if a user has many posts, you want to add a post to a user, right ? If user has many posts and you create a new post, you can do it like :

```
current_user.posts.create(...)
```

or

```
current_user.posts << post
```

Hope that is what you are looking for. If not, please specify a bit more clearly.